# Test failing on creating factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a problem concerning testing with factorygirl:

First some code:

customesr_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'


describe "customers" do
  describe "signup" do
    #FactoryGirl.find_definitions
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:signup_customer)
    it "has right data" do
      visit signup_path
      fill_in :id, :with => 2110001
      fill_in :name, :with => "AVK POLSKA Sp. zo.o."
      fill_in :email, :with => "my.email@provider.be"
      fill_in :email_confirmation, :with => "my.email@provider.be"
      click_button "Create account"
      page.should have_content("Fireprotection")
    end
end
```

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :signup_customer, class: Customer do
    id = 2110001
    name = "AVK POLSKA Sp. zo.o."
    email = ""
    address_1 = "ul. Jakubowska 1"
    address_2 = "Pniewy 62-045"
    zipcode = 62
    city = "Pniewy"
    currency = "PLN"
    country_id = "PL"
    contact_person_id = "AZU"
    reset_token = nil
    reset_token_init = nil
  end
end
```

This is the error that I get when running that test:

```
Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-rspec-2.1.1/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb",
 "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--out", "/dev/null", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec"]...
  <-- take tuple(1); slave.run...
09:17:40 - ERROR - Guard::RSpec failed to achieve its <start>, exception was:
```

> [#73C9383A03A6] DRb::DRbUnknownError: ActiveRecord::
>   [#73C9383A03A6] c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1095:in `method_missing'
>   [#73C9383A03A6] c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-rspec-2.1.1/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:124:in`run_via_drb'

Do I have to put a require somewhere? What am I missing here?

Comment: `id = 2110001` should be `id 2110001` etc..

Comment: Unfortunately, with this being changed, the same error is being thrown. But thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

First I have to mention this:

I was using Guard with Rspec and Spork on my windows pc.
-> I added Spork to have faster tests once guard and rspec were running.

What I did to solve the problem (with thanks to the freenode #RubyOnRails channel.:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:signup_customer)
#This is wrong! Has to be:
let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:signup_customer)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you init the spork? You should have some Spork.prefork blocks in your code so it know what it can keep in memory for the entire time and what it can reload upon each run. I don't see your rspec files here with the spork blocks defined.

Comment: I didn't init the spork anymore. Now I tested it with spork activated on guard and it worked, just the let(){} part was important.

Comment: Your problem is fixed, now? I use Guard and spork all the time with RSpec and FactoryGirl. I never had a problem with stuff like this before. I only use let in my model unit tests and not in my controller and I haven't had this problem. I was wondering about your forking blocks, if those were correct or not.

Comment: The problem also was that my user model only had :email as attr_accessible. So my factories didn't come out nice because of no mass-assignment to my Customer model. My tests are running perfectly now.

Comment: May I recommend you switch to strong_parameteres? It's actually quite good. It solves the problem of only letting in parameters that you actually want them to use/you can use in general AND it will protect your models just as good as attr_accessible. It's what will be use in Rails 4.0. I put it in my app in production, and I know how complete confidence in my controllers and models.